# Out-of-order arrangement of minipages, such as to manipulate subfigure captions

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, subfloats, minipage

I want to arrange 8 subfigures in Latex in this way. [image]

But the captions need to be modified in the form:

```
C   F
D A G
E B H
```

The current implementation uses three column-wise minipages.

```
    \begin{figure}[th]
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGC}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/c.png}
        }
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGD}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/d.png}
        }
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGE}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/e.png}
        }                   
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.46\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGA}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/a.png}
        }   
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGB}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/b.png}
        }               
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGF}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/f.png}
        }
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGG}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/g.png}
        }
        \subcaptionbox      
        {A RGB Image
            \label{FIGH}
        }
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
            {Figures/h.png}
        }                   
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A frictionless ball oscillating on a semi-circle.}
    \label{exam2}
\end{figure}
```

How should this be modified such that the middle column's subfigures are numbered first, followed by left and right column's?
Any lead/help is highly appreciated.